# Limit the value list combobox choices on a form

Tags: ms-access

I have a combobox (value list type) on a form. I want to limit some of the values in the combobox in this form so that the user can apply only an allowed value. If a user tries to apply another value, I want `msgbox` to display "cannot apply this value" (essentially, a custom message).

Comment: What have you tried?  What went wrong? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Every item of your list in combobox has an idItem. You could write something like
if mycombo.Itemid = 'value' then 'what you want.
I remember from visual basic, but i think you can write code by vba.
I hope was helpful